# Track by index doesnt reset after changing selection

Tags: angularjs

i have a cascading select option, and is working well, the problem is that when i change the first selected option, in the second selection option (subcategory), it keeps the index. So case i change the category (first select), in the second selection it goes to the option position that it was.

For better understanding, please check this example i made and try changin the options. You will notice that in the second selec option keeps the position index that had in the previous category selected. It doesnt starts to 0 when changing the category.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Fqfg3/28/

Js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('PeopleCtrl', function ($http,$scope) {
    vm = this;

    vm.options = [
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "label": "Category 1",
    "childs": [
      "Category 1 -> Subcategory 1",
      "Category 1 -> Subcategory 2",
      "others"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "label": "Category 2",
    "childs": [
      "Category 2 -> Subcategory 1",
      "Category 2 -> Subcategory 2",
      "others"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "label": "Category 3",
    "childs": [
       "Category 3 -> Subcategory 1",
      "Category 3 -> Subcategory 2",
      "others"
    ]
  }];


});
```

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl as ctrl" class="container">
 {{ctrl.options}}

 <div class="form-group question-wrapper">
                <select class="form-control"
                        name="category"
                        ng-options="option.label for option in ctrl.options track by option._id"
                        ng-model="ctrl.supportMail.selected">
                </select>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group question-wrapper">
                <select  id="sub" class="form-control"
                        name="subcategory"

                       >
                    <option  ng-repeat="child in ctrl.supportMail.selected.childs track by $index">{{child}}</option>

                </select>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**ng-change**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) in main select to reset the subselect to default.

Here's is a demonstration working:

```js
(function() {
"use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function() {
      var vm = this;

      vm.options = [  
         {  
            "_id":"1",
            "label":"Category 1",
            "childs":[  
               "Category 1 -> Subcategory 1",
               "Category 1 -> Subcategory 2",
               "others"
            ]
         },
         {  
            "_id":"2",
            "label":"Category 2",
            "childs":[  
               "Category 2 -> Subcategory 1",
               "Category 2 -> Subcategory 2",
               "others"
            ]
         },
         {  
            "_id":"3",
            "label":"Category 3",
            "childs":[  
               "Category 3 -> Subcategory 1",
               "Category 3 -> Subcategory 2",
               "others"
            ]
         }
      ];

      vm.reset_subSelect = function() {
        vm.supportMail.child = vm.supportMail.selected.childs[0];
      }
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group question-wrapper">
      <select class="form-control" name="category" ng-options="option.label for option in ctrl.options track by option._id" ng-model="ctrl.supportMail.selected" ng-change="ctrl.reset_subSelect()" ng-init="ctrl.supportMail.selected = ctrl.options[0]">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group question-wrapper">
      <select class="form-control" id="sub" name="subcategory" ng-options="child for child in ctrl.supportMail.selected.childs" ng-model="ctrl.supportMail.child" ng-init="ctrl.supportMail.child = ctrl.supportMail.selected.childs[0]">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible in the select box appear already the data instead appearing blank options.

Comment: You mean the first object? If yes, I edited the answer.

Comment: yes, appear the first option/object in category and subcategory, but there is a tricky part, the solutions i found online uses the index to get the first one, but then creates a problem, it gets duplicates in the subcategory for example

Comment: Have you tested it?

Answer (score 1):

By adding an `ng-model` to your subcategory I was able to resolve the issue you can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lcfcqh4/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see, one more question, is is possible in the selecti options already appear the information in the first option, instead of having it blank.

Comment: if you just want the first item in the sub category selected you can add an ng-change function and set it like so                                            `vm.setSub = function(item){
     vm.supportMail.selectedChild = vm.supportMail.selected.childs[0];
    };`   `ng-change="ctrl.setSub()"`

Comment: The problem is when using vm.supportMail.selected.childs[0] it gets duplicates.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by duplicated here is the example I have that seems to work.  Please provide further explanation as to the duplication.  http://jsfiddle.net/5Lcfcqh4/3/